# Java multidimensional arrays - How to refer to the length of different dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

We are learning about 2D arrays in my AP computer science A class and I have a question that I'm struggling to find the clear answer to. For some context when I'm talking about my question, ragged arrays are out of the picture and when I refer to rows I am talking about arrays going across and when I refer to columns I'm talking about arrays that go up in down in the matrix.

Example of a matrix with 2 rows and 4 columns:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

My question is how would I refer to the column length and the row length. In some online resources I have looked at, it describes the number of rows as `arr.length` and the number of columns as `arr[0].length` (I know that could be `arr[1].length` as well but since I'm not talking about ragged arrays I'm just going to use 0) and in other places it describes the row length as `arr[0].length`.

On my test I was marked incorrect for saying that the column length is `arr.length` and the correct answer was `arr[0].length`. I've seen various answers online and in lecture videos I have watched so I wanted to clarify here.

Edit: I'm specifically asking if `arr.length` refers to the column length; I know that is refers to the number of rows.

Comment: `arr.length` - to refer to the first dimension size; `arr[idx].length` - to refer to the second dimension size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On my test I was marked incorrect for saying that the column length is arr.length and the correct answer was `arr[0].length`

Well, there is your problem. The Java Language Specification does not mention the notion of 'row' or 'column'. It'd have been mighty strange if it did. It's a *programming language*, the whole **point** of them is that they are flexible constructs and the world is your oyster. Program whatever you like.

Which gets us to this simple truth: The language provides arrays and dimensional syntax (even if java doesn't really multidimensional arrays, it's just arrays-of-arrays). **You make up everything else, notably including the concept of row and column**.

In other words, `arr.length` is the row length, and `arr[0].length` is the column length? Okay. Well, you tell me. It's your program.

Your teacher is really wrong here, capital W: Not just that they marked down "`arr.length` is the row" (because that is not wrong. It is also not right, it is a fundamental misunderstanding - it's like saying: "That feeling is tuna" - 2 concepts that are **utterly** unrelated), but mostly that they are perpetuating a significant brainfart by even suggesting that there is such a thing: By suggesting that it is even meaningful to state, in blanket fashion, that dim1 is rows and dim2 is columns (or vice versa) for **all java code** out there.

I take it all back, though, if the point of saying 'Say, Benny, you are wrong - `arr.length` is **not** the number of columns' is to explain to you that it isn't the number of rows either: It's whatever you want it to represent. It's also possible you've glossed over other parts, for example, if the question is shaped more like this:

```
int[][] chessBoard = new int[8][8];
chessBoard[1][0] = new Knight(Color.WHITE);
```

In this specific example, assuming that it's fair game to presume knowledge of the rules of chess (dubious but then I'm not responsible for teaching), you may safely conclude that `chessBoard.length` gives you the number of columns, and `chessBoard[0].length` the number of rows; after all, the first row, second column does indeed start out containing a knight, whereas the second row, first column certainly does not (it holds a pawn).

But that is **only** because whoever wrote that snippet of chess software decreed it so. They could have decreed that the first 'dimension' is the row and the second is the column just the same. It'd have an obvious effect on just about every other line of code that interacts with the `chessBoard` array, but the code is no less or more valid and no less or more weird.

TL;DR: Either you misjudged the point of this question or your teacher is didactically speaking completely off.

NB: Note that absolutely nothing in your question indicates on its own which decree has been made: That 'first dimension' holds rows and 'second dimension' holds columns or vice versa. Your example of:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

still doesn't mean anything. That's like showing me a picture of a chess board, that still doesn't explain which java array dimension maps to which dimension in your picture. Had the example included *java code*, different story. Another example of this:

Had the question read instead:

> Example of a matrix with 2 rows and 4 columns.

> ```
> int[][] matrix =
>    {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0};
> ```

Then the code gives away the answer. Evidently, the first dimension is rows and the second is columns (because `matrix.length` would return `2` and `matrix[0].length` would return `4`, and the question literally states "This code represents a matrix of 2 rows and 4 columns". Both pieces (the code and the question preamble) together only make sense if the decree is made that dim1 = rows, dim2 = cols.

For what it is worth, I bet that if you do a deep scan of all java code on all of github, that dim1 = rows and dim2 = cols is significantly more common than the reverse, for all 2D matrix code that clearly represents something that can be conceptualized as 'a thing with rows and columns'. But I absolutely guarantee you that there is perfectly fine code out there that uses dim1 = cols and dim2 = rows, and if you file a bug report to switch them, you will be correctly. laughed out of their issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth clarification. In my class, we are required to follow the curriculum that the College board creates and in this case, they said that rows and columns follow my definition in the original question. My test question was fairly similar to the last example you gave; it declared an array as ```int [][] arr = new int[5][6];``` and asked which of the following represents the column length: ```arr[0].length``` or ```arr.length```.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow rather obviously cannot tell you what your curriculum decrees, especially not if you mention neither the cirriculum nor the section of the book that makes that boneheaded decree. Can you still switch schools? This is so utterly irrelevant to becoming a programmer, let alone a good one, it boggles the mind.

Comment: I agree that this has nothing to with being a good programmer but as of now, this question being marked wrong changes my entire grade from an A to a B+ as it was only a 5 question multipole choice test. Here is a link to the course exam and description and it declares what row and column mean for the course on page 136 on the righthand side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

So if you were to run the following:

`exampleArray.length`

- would only print the the number of rows because there is no bracket value, when you do the .length of anything, that is the length of string in Java. The string length method basically returns the amount of characters that were produced in that string. It returns the length of any string.

`exampleArray[0].length` prints the number of columns of the first row

- when you do 1 of these [] brackets this indicates the number of columns in each row. So if you do [0], that means in the 1st row, the number of columns would be printed.

`exampleArray[1].length` prints the number of columns of the second row

- same concept but instead it would print out the number of columns of the second row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create two dimensional array
    int[][] exampleArray = new int[][] {new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4}};

    System.out.println(exampleArray.length);    //Prints 2
    System.out.println(exampleArray[0].length); //Prints 3
    System.out.println(exampleArray[1].length); //Prints 4
}
```

In the example above I created a two dimensional array with two rows, where the first row contains numbers 1, 2 & 3 (3 columns) and the second row contains numbers 1, 2, 3 & 4 (4 columns).

If you run the code you'll find out that:

- *exampleArray.length* prints the number of rows
- *exampleArray[0].length* prints the number of columns of the first row
- *exampleArray[1].length* prints the number of columns of the second row

**Edit:** In your specific example with the array you have given us the column length is 2 and *arr.length* which is the number of rows is also 2. But, you shouldn't make any assumptions from that. This is something that is true for this specific array you've given us as an example. You shouldn't draw out of this any generic rule that can be applied elsewhere. When using *arr.length* you are referring to the array's number of rows. It's not safe to draw any conclusions about its columns just from this value, without more information about the array.

Comment: I know that ```exampleArray[0].length``` is the number of columns in the first row and my question is asking if that means that ```exampleArray.length``` not only equals the number of rows, but also the column length (if it was not a ragged array).

Comment: No; a ragged array means that the columns could be of different lengths. If it is not a ragged array it means that every row has the same number of columns, but that doesn’t necessarily mean you have the same number of rows as columns. If the rows and columns were the same it would be classified as a square array.

Comment: @AIBlue exactly , couldn't have explained it better myself!!

Comment: Im aware of that and in the example I gave in my question, it is not a square array and my statement is still true. Each row has a length of 4 and 4 is also the number of columns, this is also true for columns as each column has a length of 2 and there are 2 rows. number of rows = column length and number of columns = row length.

Comment: @BennyEisner I edited my answer after understanding your thoughts, trying to clarify some  things.

Comment: In response to your edit, we only focused on rectangular 2 dimensional arrays so for example dimensions of [3][6] or [5][9] or [5][2] etc. Taking this into account, would there be any scenario in which the number of rows doesn't equal the column length? (again no ragged arrays)

Comment: If an array in not ragged then it's rectagular. By definition in rectangular arrays the number of rows is different to the number of columns. Except if it's square. Now the phrase "number of rows" is equivalent to the phrase "column length". The same way the phrase "number of columns" is equivalent to the phrase "row length". But, people usually don't use the  phrases column length & row length since they can be misleading.

Comment: @ThanasisM thank you for the clarification and your help!

Comment: @BennyEisner you're welcome. The conclusion is that depending on someone's perspective you can describe something with different words but still mean the same thing.

Comment: @BennyEisner if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @ThanasisM yes ill do that i didnt know your could do that im new here thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the array you’re referring to here is an array-of-arrays. The dimension of this array is the number of rows in your content; then each one inside the array is the number of columns. So your mark was correct in this case.

Comment: Nope. 'row' and 'column' aren't anywhere in the JLS. They are arbitrary constructs you just made up.

Comment: They are constructs that the AP Computer Science A Class created so we must follow them since my class follows the AP curriculum.

Comment: I was using rows and columns as defined in the question.

Comment: @AlBlue I don't recognize anything in the question that clearly ties either the word 'row' or the word 'column' to the first or second dimension.